# How to interpret 緩やかな風で森がざわめく音だけが、闇を飾るように聞こえてくる。

Tags: grammar, meaning, interpretation

I was reading a light novel and saw this sentence describing how it feels like in a forest.

> 緩やかな風で森がざわめく音だけが、闇を飾るように聞こえてくる。

I understand every word in it, but I am confused as to what sounds can be heard.

To me, it is not clear what だけ modifies, does this mean:

- 聞こえる音はただ一つ、緩やかな風で森がざわめく音だ or;
- 他の音も聞こえるが、**闇を飾るように**ではなく、他のように聞こえる。つまり、緩やかな風で森がざわめく音だけが闇を飾る。他の音は闇を飾らない

Which interpretation is correct? Or are both correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both interpretations are technically possible, but only the former seems natural to me. This is a dark and relatively silent forest, isn't it? 闇を飾るように is a fairly vague and poetic expression and I have never tried to distinguish sounds according to such a criterion. If it were something like 森がざわめく音だけが前から聞こえてくる, the sentence might seem ambiguous and there might be other sound sources behind you.

Comment: Ah, right. That makes sense. The sentences before the quoted sentence talks about how dark the forest is, but not how noisy it is.